# Report Viewer Returns rsAccessDenied When Accessed by Domain Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

I'm building an ASP .NET web application that contains a viewer for SQL Server reports. The viewer is supplied by the [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms) package.

When connecting using localhost the report appears fine, but when connecting using a domain name ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) this text appears instead:

> The permissions granted to user 'hardcodeddomain\hardcodeduser' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

I don't know why using a different host name changes the result but the application is quite simple.

Reports.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Title" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Reports.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportingPortal.WebForms.Reports" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="rsweb" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer Width="100%" ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote">
        <ServerReport></ServerReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</asp:Content>
```

Reports.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace ReportingPortal.WebForms
{
    public partial class Reports : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) return;
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials();
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/example/report/path";
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportServerUrl"));
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the SQL Server Reporting Services web portal (for me it was at http://localhost/reports/browse)
2. Go to "Manage folder"
3. Click "Add group or user"
4. Enter the username of the hardcoded user
5. Check on all the permissions (or the ones required for your use-case)
6. Click OK

For some reason this affects if the user can access a report through a domain name or not. I thought the security in "Site settings" would be sufficient but apparently not!